# REGEX: How to ignore table of contents when grabbing text between two chapters?

Tags: python, regex

I want to grab content in Chapter 1, but it keeps getting the table of contents instead.

I've tried this `Chapter 1((.*\n)*)Chapter 2`, but it would grab the table of contents. If I manually remove the table of contents, it would work fine.

Full text:

```
1. Chapter 1
2. Chapter 2
3. Chapter 3

Chapter 1
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum\

Chapter 2
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
```

Comment: What flavour of regex? JS, PHP, python etc.?

Comment: @Nick its python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a flavour of regex that supports lookbehind, you can use a negative lookbehind for `\d.` before `Chapter 1` to avoid matching `Chapter 1` in the table of contents. By including `Chapter 1` as a positive lookbehind, and using a positive lookahead for `Chapter 2` you can make your desired text the entire match:

```
(?<=(?<!\d. )Chapter 1).*(?=Chapter 2)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/H3ANCn/2/)

Note you need to use the `s` flag to make `.` match newline.